# Beginner's questions about multithreading in Java and usage of synchronized blocks and wait()/notify()

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, synchronized, notify

Im learning about synchronization mechanisms in Java. And this an example code that i was given to analyze. Sorry about the missing code, but the story is simple. We have 2 Consumers and 4 Producers who are implemented as Threads and they call these get and put methods respectively in a while loop.

The question is why exactly do we come to a deadlock?
Also, if you could answer me some of questions on my mind.

1. Is there a difference between the Monitor who deals with threads that communicate with notify and wait and the Monitor who looks after that no two threads enter a synchronization method (get or put)? That is, when one thread inside of the put method calls notify(), is another thread which is waiting to get inside of the put method a valid candidate to take over the Monitor?
2. Is the answer to my main question so "obvious and dumb" that while one thread is inside wait() of the method put, no other thread can enter both method put and get to notify it which makes the deadlock happen?
3. What is the difference between notify and notifyAll?

   ```
   public synchronized void put(Object o) throws InterruptedException {
       while (count == size) {
           wait();
       }
       buf[in] = o;
       //System.out.println("PUT from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
       ++count;
       in = (in + 1) % size;
       notifyAll(); // if this is not a notifyAll() we might notify the wrong waiter
     }

   public synchronized Object get() throws InterruptedException {
      while (count == 0) {
          wait();
      }
      Object o = buf[out];
      buf[out] = null;
      //System.out.println("GET from " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
      --count;
      out = (out + 1) % size;
      notifyAll(); // if this is not a notifyAll() we might notify the wrong waiter
      return (o);
   }
   ```

Comment: I think perhaps if you were given this to analyze that you should do your own work.

Comment: Regarding #3 I think you should [read the documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#notify--)  Regarding the monitors I think you also need to read up on how they work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is under number two which makes my official job done. Its not my fault i have no official literature for this class and my "own work" constitutes of googling, and after a long time of having no luck regarding question no.1 i decided to ask it myself. Questions no.2 and 3 are just something i wanted to ask when im already here. 


No need for that kind of attitude when im posting online to "learn more". If you don't feel like answering you can just skip the page.

Comment: In the real world, reading the documentation is normal and expected.  For your question, I'm concerned about your "monitor who.." and "monitor who..."  There's almost certainly only one monitor being used here.  You should review the code and be certain you're confident that you understand how many monitors are in use, and what object they are associated with.

Comment: Also I feel I should say something regarding "pedagogical malpractice."  If you're really a beginner at coding (not just Java) then yes, this question is unreasonably hard.  If you're more advanced though, this question is an excellent example of *why* you want to use the API as Brian Goetz suggests;  it shows exactly where the sharp edges of notify/wait are (especially notify vs notifyAll).

Comment: @markspace Thats the thing. I'm finding it really hard to learn (and thats the biggest point of my question here on stackoverflow) how do synchronized methods interact with wait() and notify() methods. Does a Thread that can't get into a synchronized method because some other Thread is already running that method have the same status as some Thread that was stopped with the wait() method? Are both of those Threads treated equal by the Monitor? Is it even the same Monitor?

I know what my options are and that i can read documentations indefinitely, but im having problems finding what i want.

Comment: Re, "why exactly do we come to a deadlock?"  _Does_ the program deadlock?  The two methods that you show look crude, but safe.  If the program fails to perform the way you expect, how do you know that the problem isn't somewhere else?  What does the rest of the program look like?

Comment: The [Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html) is a good place to start. "Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it" (where "intrinsic lock" =  monitor).  That's "a" monitor per object, only one monitor per object.  As for wait/notify, the behavior of those methods is different than a monitor blocked with `synchronized` so I surmise that the status of a thread blocked on a monitor and one blocked on wait() are different.

Answer (score 0):

> Is the answer to my main question so "obvious and dumb" that while one thread is inside wait() of the method put, no other thread can enter both method put and get to notify it which makes the deadlock happen?

`o.wait()` performs a sequence of steps:

- It releases the lock on `o`,
- It waits until another thread calls `o.notify()`,
- It waits until the lock becomes available again,
- It re-locks the lock, and then finally
- It returns.

So when one thread is in a `wait()` call inside a `put(o)` call, another thread can be executing inside a `get()` or a `put()` call.